# Check to see if AddThis is loaded, then trigger a link banner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addthis

I'm looking to load a banner once AddThis loads on the page, or when it becomes viewable. Unfortunately, everything I've tried has failed. Tried the suggested code from the site, but hasn't worked, just throws a referenceerror, and am not sure what to try next.

Here's the code from the site:

```
// Alert a message when the AddThis API is ready
function addthisReady(evt) {
    alert('AddThis API is fully loaded.');
}

// Listen for the ready event
addthis.addEventListener('addthis.ready', addthisReady);
```

Here's the link to the page: [AddThis JavaScript Events](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1365497-addthis-javascript-events)

Answer (score 6):

Tanel is right. The problem is that addthis object has not been initialized before calling. Here's a simple solution, that I used for my website:

```
var addThisTimer = setInterval(function() {
    if (typeof addthis !== 'undefined') {
        clearInterval(addThisTimer);
        addthis.addEventListener('addthis.ready', function() {
            console.log('AddThis API is fully loaded.');
        });
    }
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually initialized the addthis object before listening to the event? If not, that's most likely your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, how do I do that. Can't anything regarding that in their documentation.

Comment: I'm sorry, are you talking about `addthis.init();`?

Comment: I had a quick look at their docs and seems like they might be creating the addthis object in their own javascript. So try adding the listener after their javascript has been included.